# Meaning of numbers inside parentheses in Lattice Synthesis Engine Utilization Report?

Tags: fpga, synthesis, lattice

I'm using Lattice Radiant 2.0 to synthesize a design. In the "Synthesis Utilization Report file", I see the following line:

```
                  LUT4    PFU Registers   IO Buffers   DSPMULT     EBR   Carry Cells
 toplevel    2752(267)          702(74)       22(21)      5(0)   30(2)      315(315)
```

The numbers outside the parentheses are pretty clear; that's just resource usage.

My questions:

- What do the numbers inside the parentheses mean?
- Is this standard notation for synthesizer outputs? If so, where can I find information explaining standard synthesizer output notation?

I've already looked through the following documents, but haven't been able to find anything (warning: links auto-download PDFs (Lattice's decision, not mine.))

- [Lattice synthesis engine user guide](http://www.latticesemi.com/%7E/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/UserManuals/JL/LSEUGDiamond.pdf?document_id=51556)
- [Lattice Radiant Software 2.0 User Guide](https://www.latticesemi.com/view_document?document_id=52759)
- [Lattice Radiant Software 2.0 Help](https://www.latticesemi.com/view_document?document_id=52750)
- [Lattice Radiant Software 2.0 Tutorial](https://www.latticesemi.com/view_document?document_id=52758)

My only guess is that the number in parentheses describes how many resources could be optimized out of the design with more aggressive optimization strategies, but I have nothing to base that guess off of.

Comment: FWIW, Quartus uses a <used>/<available> format.

Comment: Just a guess - could it be before/after optimization?

Comment: I don't think so; there are 2752 LUTs and 30 EBRs actually in use in the bitstream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my calculation, the number inside the parentheses is the usage of the module itself excluding submodule instances. The number before is the total of the architecture:

[image: Calculation on my design : ICE40 is close to be full!]

This means that in your case, the top module uses 267 LUT and the rest of the design uses: 2752-267=2485

Comment: This looks awesome!..... just wish they could have said it somewhere in their documentation.